# How to null check and return a value in a generic way

Tags: java

I have a long list of object mapping to do from classes auto generated by JAXB.

```
 customer.setCustomerId(rentalCustomer.getCustomerid().getValue()));
 customer.setCustomerName(rentalCustomer.getTradingname().getValue());
 customer.setVatNumber(rentalSearchCustomer.getVatNumber().getValue());
 ....
 ....
```

Basically I need to make a null check for ALL fields:

```
getValue(RentalCustomerIDType idType){
  if(idType != null){
    return idType.getValue();
  }
  else {
   return "";
 }
}
```

Problem is there are too many of these and they all have different types: RentalCustomerIDType, TradingType, VatNumberType..etc

Is there an elegant way to this by creating a **GENERIC** method that makes null check and return proper values for **ALL** maybe using Functional Libraries for Java?

Comment: is `idType.getValue()` always going to be a String?  Or could it also be other types?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong always string

Comment: Ok, then we just need to find something that is in common about all of these methods you want to call.  Do these types all extend a certain class or implement a certain interface?  Are all of the methods named `getValue()`?  Otherwise we just have to write out a big long switch-case statement.

Comment: Use reflection, populate nulls with a default value and use the Class.newInstance() method for non-primitives. (You can test if it's a primitive or not with the reflection api)

Comment: @Spring I would suggest not screaming at the people who are trying to help you and are asking clarifying questions in order to do so.

Comment: OK, a point of confusion.  Do all getValue() method's return a String?  If not, what do they return.  And what are examples of the classes that house the getValue() method.

Comment: @WJS I really appreciate your interest on helping. but it looks like not possible without using Reflection. getvalue() is always string. but each type has its own getValue() method. so its not one method.

Comment: @Spring It just dawned on me what the issue is. Sorry about my persistence. But this is an interesting problem so I am going to continue looking at it. But I have one simple question? Did you write classes for each type that has the getValue() method?  Or does each type implement some interface that specifies the `getValue` method?

Comment: @WJS it’s jaxb created

Comment: @Spring Thanks. I've exhausted my ideas.  If you can get the Interface or can specify one for getValue(), my solution should work.  Otherwise you will have to use reflection.  Regards!!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use reflection on the class when it's generated and eliminate all nulls by assigning non-null values to the fields?

[Check an replace null values in multiple variables java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199856/check-an-replace-null-values-in-multiple-variables-java)

They say (the guy who answered) that they strongly disagree with using reflection for this purpose... but... meh. I've done it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic method to declare the `getValueFromAllObjects` method and then use reflection to invoke the `getValue` method

```
public static <T> String getValueFromAllObjects(T t) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
  if(t != null){
    return (String) t.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getValue").invoke(t);
  }
  else {
   return "";
 }
}
```

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883454/442256 for reflection alternatives. I've just inlined an example in your code above

Comment: The OP said *pls notice getValue() is specific for type*.   So getValue() returns different types. You would need one of these methods for each type.  You can't assign a String to all types.

Comment: I've assumed it is String as that what he's clarified in the comment [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65692652/how-to-null-check-and-return-a-value-in-a-generic-way/65693438?noredirect=1#comment116149551_65692652)

Comment: That was for `idType`.  There are other types.

Comment: @WJS the return of an empty String "" in the getValue() function implies String

Comment: @sfk thx sfk. Didnt test but I think this is the only answer here that can get he job done. But unfortunately not very reluctant to use reflections,,but I apprecciate your answer +1

Comment: @Spring no worries, if it helps arguing the case "for" reflection, JAXB uses it quite heavily and so do DI frameworks such as Spring

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you do not want to be changing existing auto-generated classes. What you can do is create a `CustomerWrapper` class that wraps `Customer` and inserts defaults when a `null` is set to a field. This is the idea in code:

```java
public class CustomerWrapper() {

    private final Customer customer;

    public CustomerWrapper(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String id) {
        this.customer.setCustomerId(id == null ? "" : id);
    }

    // Insert other methods here.

}
```

Comment: writing a wrapper that handles all different types for all fields is not more elegant then checking nulls

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want.  But there is a caveat.  Each type must implement the same interface that provides the `getValue()` method.   Otherwise, you will probably need reflection to get the method as you suspected.  But here is a solution for posterity.

```
setType(rentalSearchCustomer::getCustomerid,
        customer::setCustomerId);
setType(rentalSearchCustomer::getTradingname,
        customer::setCustomerName);
setType(rentalSearchCustomer::getVatNumber,
        customer::setVatNumber);
System.out.println(customer);
        
    
    
public static <T extends GetValue> void setType(Supplier<T> sup,
        Consumer<String> con) {
    if (sup.get() == null) {
        con.accept("");
    } else {
        con.accept(sup.get().getValue());
    }
}
    
interface GetValue {
    public String getValue();
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.Your example shows optional accepts a string how do you send RentalSearchCustomerIDType to your getValue method? and imagine that type is different for all fields

Comment: thx but its missing the getValue() method of my custom type object pls notice getValue() is specific for type

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use something like. here I have taken ResponseUserDto as my Pojo Class for null checks of it's properties.

```
private ResponseUserDto getValidNotNullPropertyObject(Object source) {
    final BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
    Map < String, Object > result = new HashMap<>();
    for (PropertyDescriptor property: src.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        if (src.getPropertyValue(property.getName()) == null) {
            /* if(property.getPropertyType() == ?) {
                    //maybe do somethig here
                }*/
            result.put(property.getName(), ""); // this is start
        } else {
            result.put(property.getName(), src.getPropertyValue(property.getName()));
        }
    }
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // Jackson's ObjectMapper
    final ResponseUserDto finalResult = mapper.convertValue(result, ResponseUserDto.class);
    return finalResult;
}
```

and to use this, you can call it like this

```
return this.getValidNotNullPropertyObject(responseUserDto);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe a case for Aspect Oriented Programming, if its use is an option:

- using an [Advice](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-advice.html) in AspectJ (see `around advice`)
- or (I have not checked this) Spring AOP [How to change the return value by spring aop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14017951/13510609) (closed, but has one answer)